# Python: Twilio TaskRouter Conference Instruction

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter, twilio-python, twilio-conference

I'm handling incoming call using TaskRouter with conference instruction like so

```
@csrf_exempt
def TaskEnqueue(request):
    """ Put call into queue """
    response = VoiceResponse()
    digits = request.POST['Digits']
    selected_service = 'Support' if digits == '1' else 'Sales'
    task = {'selected_service': selected_service}

    enqueue = response.enqueue(None, workflowSid=TWILIO_WORKFLOW_SID)
    enqueue.task(json.dumps(task))

    return HttpResponse(
        str(response), content_type='application/xml; charset=utf-8'
    )

@csrf_exempt
def TaskAssignmentView(request):    
    """ Task assignment """
    worker_attributes = json.loads(request.POST['WorkerAttributes'])
    assigned_worder_uri = worker_attributes['contact_uri']


    response = {'instruction': 'conference',
                'from': TWILIO_NUMBER,
                'to': assigned_worder_uri,
                'end_conference_on_exit': True,
                'post_work_activity_sid': TWILIO_ACTIVITY_BREAK}

    return JsonResponse(response)
```

I'd like to end conference after either agent or caller hangs up.

Even with "end_conference_on_exit" property the conference is ended only when agent hangs up but not when caller hangs up.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's enough to add "end_conference_on_customer_exit" to the conference instruction.

```
response = {'instruction': 'conference',
                'from': TWILIO_NUMBER,
                'to': assigned_worder_uri,
                'end_conference_on_exit': True,
                'post_work_activity_sid': TWILIO_ACTIVITY_BREAK,

                'end_conference_no_customer_exit': True
}
```